# Iterating over CSV reader object in Python

Tags: python, csv, iterator

I have two CSV files, one of which is likely to contain a few more records that the other. I am writing a function to iterate over each and determine which records are in dump but not liar.

My code is as follows:

```
def update_lib(x, y):
    dump = open(x, newline='')
    libr = open(y, newline='')
    dump_reader = csv.reader(dump)
    for dump_row in dump_reader:
        libr_reader = csv.reader(libr)
        for libr_row in libr_reader:
            if dump_row[0] == libr_row[0]:
                break
```

I am expecting this to take the first row in dump (dump_row) and iterate over each row in library (libr_row) to see if the first elements match. If they do then I want to move to the next row in dump and if not I will do something else eventually.

My issue is that libr_reader appears to "remember" where it is and I can't get it to go back to the first row in libr, even when the `break` has been reached and I would therefore expect libr_reader to be re-initiated. I have even tried `del libr_row` and `del libr_reader` but this doesn't appear to make a difference. I suspect I am misunderstanding iterators, any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it's pasted in your question, you'll be creating a `libr_reader` object *every time* you iterate over a row in `dump_reader`.

```
dump_reader = csv.reader(dump)
for dump_row in dump_reader:
    libr_reader = csv.reader(libr)
```

`dump_reader` here is created once. Assuming there are 10 rows from `dump_reader`, you will be creating 10 `libr_reader` instances, all from the same file handle.

Per our discussion in the comments, you're aware of that, but what you're unaware of is that the reader object is working on the same file handle and thus, is still at the same cursor.

Consider this example:

```
>>> import io
>>> my_file = io.StringIO("""Line 1
... Another Line
... Finally, a third line.""")
```

This is creating a simulated file object. Now I'll create a "LineReader" class.

```
>>> class LineReader:
...     def __init__(self, file):
...         self.file = file
...     def show_me_a_line(self):
...         print(self.file.readline())
...
```

If I use *three* line readers on the same file, the file still remembers its place:

```
>>> line_reader = LineReader(my_file)
>>> line_reader.show_me_a_line()
Line 1

>>> second_line_reader = LineReader(my_file)
>>> second_line_reader.show_me_a_line()
Another Line

>>> third_line_reader = LineReader(my_file)
>>> third_line_reader.show_me_a_line()
Finally, a third line.
```

To the `my_file` object, there's no material difference between what I just did, and doing this directly. First, I'll "reset" the file to the beginning by calling seek(0):

```
>>> my_file.seek(0)
0
>>> my_file.readline()
'Line 1\n'
>>> my_file.readline()
'Another Line\n'
>>> my_file.readline()
'Finally, a third line.'
```

There you have it.

So TL/DR: Files have cursors and remember where they are. Think of the file handle as a thing that remembers where the file is, yes, but also remembers where in the file your program is.

Comment: That was intentional (if incorrect) in order to attempt to "reset" the libr_reader each time. The behaviour was the same when, initially, I only created it once.

Comment: Oh, I see. I think to "reset" it, you'd probably need to "seek" the file handle back to the beginning of the file. But really, if you have enough memory, you should probably just load both files into memory as data structures and use the data structures.

Comment: I see, thanks, do you mean convert these into lists? I'm also interested in understanding why the iteration remembers its place even when re-created...

Comment: @TomTry ok, I updated the answer with a bit of an explanation of how files work. This is actually the same in Python, C, or just about any programming language. Does that help?